# select query in oracle that will output the sysdate and sysdate+1 (YYYY-YYYY)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

How to create a select query on oracle that will select the present year and present year +1

sample table

```
Col1
2016-2017
2017-2018
2018-2019
2018-2019
```

```
select count(*) from tablename
where Col1 = sysdate||-||sysdate+1;
```

and the output must be 2, because the present year was 2018 and present year increment by 1 is 2019 which will become 2018-2019

how to create a correct and proper query for select that works like this

this was for the source query of the dashboard in oracle apex 5.1

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Your table contains the four rows shown and you want to select the fourth one? But what for would you need the table; current year till next is '2018-2019' with or without that table.

Answer (score 2):

At first you need to get the year from `sysdate`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate)
from dual
;
```

and using your own concatenation then leads to what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate) as currentyear,
(EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate) + 1) as nextyear,
EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate) || ' - ' || (EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate) + 1) as concat
from dual
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TO_CHAR` and `ADD_MONTHS`

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tablename
WHERE Col1=TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')||'-'||TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,12),'YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_CHAR`

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM tablename
 WHERE Col1 =
          TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') || '-' || (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + 1);
```